# Refer to a workbooks by index number

Tags: excel, vba

I am using

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
```

to create a new workbook. I need to refer to this workbook without saving it. So I am using workbook index number to refer to the new workbook, is there a way to retrieve the index number of the last workbook open/created (the highest index number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to get the last workbook

```
Set LastWorkbook = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
```

**BUT** if you already have the `NewBook` variable, can't you just use that? The reason i say that is because relying on a `workbook`'s index may not give consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

For the highest index number, you can just use Worksheets.Count.  That'll return how many sheets you have, thus telling you the highest index.